# Google calendar API and node js - "googleAuth is not a constructor" issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to set up Google calendar API on Node, using the Node.js quick start that appear [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs)

After following all the first 3 steps and running my quickstart.js to check if it works (which i copied and pasted from the quickstart) , i get the following error:

"TypeError: googlAuth is not a constructor"
it refer to this line of code :

```
  var auth = new googleAuth();
```

googleAuth is declared like that:

```
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
```

i couldnt find any solution online.

the full code is on the link above on the third step.
thanks in advance,
Assaf.

Comment: Please add the code on the question. If the link changes or go offline in the future, your question will be outdated...

Comment: Which version of the google-auth-library are you using? If 1.x then there are breaking changes which affect default exports, see https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/releases/tag/1.0.0-alpha.1. The guide you are following uses google-auth-library@0.* (see Step 2: Install the client library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is mostly a nodejs and google library installation problem. I'm running `node v8.2.1` on my system and I'm able to execute  the nodejs quickstart properly. Try installing latest nodejs and execute these lines again.

```
npm install googleapis --save
npm install google-auth-library@0.* --save
```

Comment: What version of `googleapis` do you have installed? Starting somewhere in the `v20`s if not before, the API was updated in such a way that most of the existing documentation outside of GitHub doesn't work. For example, [the Gmail Node quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) wants `v27` but the calls are all from the older, pre-ES6 API.

Answer (score 11):

The version has changed like answers here say. According to the new [docs](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/releases/tag/v1.0.0), you must require the package like this:

```
const gal = require('google-auth-library');
const auth = new gal.GoogleAuth();
const jwtClient = new gal.JWT();
const oAuth2Client = new gal.OAuth2Client();
...
// if you're using Node 6+, you might find this convenient:
const {GoogleAuth, JWT, OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
```

The old way used to be like this:

```
var GoogleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
var auth = new GoogleAuth();
var jwtClient = new auth.JWT();
var oAuth2Client = new auth.OAuth2();
```

Basically what changed is the way to reference `GoogleAuth`. It is now one part of the entire package instead of being the main export.

This change worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Google recently released version `1.0.0`. If you installed without a version `npm` would have installed the latest. In that case your code should be:

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const auth = new GoogleAuth();
```

Comment: this causes a new issue, auth.OAuth2 is not a constructor, var auth = new GoogleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);